# Optimization problem with recursive functions

Tags: optimization, bayesian-optimization, recursive-model

I could image that the following is a standard optimization problem but nevertheless I have no clue how to specifically solve it: by which specific approach, algorithm, and which computing powers I would need?

Please let me state the problem, then every hint how to approach it is welcome!

Given a recursive formula, that gives the value of a function $f$ at time $t+1$ as a function $F$ of its values at all previous times $t, t-1,\dots,0$ and of a big number $n$ (say $n =50$) of parameters $a_i \in [0,1]$, which may vary over time:

$$f(0) = f_0$$
$$f(t+1) = F\big(f(t-1), f(t-1),\dots, f(0); a_1(t),a_2(t),\dots,a_n(t)\big)$$

Given also a cumulative cost function $c$ with

$$c(0) = 0$$

$$c(t+1) = c(t) + C\big(a_1(t),a_2(t),\dots,a_n(t)\big)$$

Finally an explicit threshold function $\vartheta(t)$.

The problem is (for a given time $T$):

> For which choice of parameters $a_1(t),a_2(t),\dots,a_n(t)$, $t < T$
>   does hold
>
> - $f(t) \leq \vartheta(t)$ for all $t \leq T$
> - $c(T)$ is minimal with value $c_{\text{min}}$

I.e. for any other choice of parameters, either $f(t) > \vartheta(t)$ for some $t \leq T$ or $c(T) > c_{\text{min}}$.

I would be more than happy not only with really optimal solutions, but also with almost optimal ones (given high probability, that they are nearly optimal).

---

Maybe the problem becomes significantly easier to solve, when we don't try to minimize $c(T)$ but fix the minimal costs $c_{\text{min}}$ and look for solutions (= choices of parameters) with

> - $f(t) \leq \vartheta(t)$ for all $t \leq T$
> - $c(T) \leq c_{\text{min}}$

---

**Edit:** Maybe the problem becomes easier when taking into account, that $F$ in fact only depends on $f(t)$ and $f(t-1)$ and $\sum_{\tau = 0}^t f(\tau)$.

Comment: Your notation is a little deceptive, because "$F$" is not a single function: it is a series of functions, one for each $t.$ As such, the recursive formulation is no restriction at all: you might as well ask how to optimize *any* function of $n$ variables subject to $T$ constraints.  That's a vast topic; I don't see how it would be possible to address it here.

Comment: Is there something to say about the $a_i(t)$? Can your restrict the formulation of these functions based on some prior knowledge?

Comment: @whuber: Does it help to restrict $F$ to depend on three arguments, as stated in my edit:$f(t+1) = F(f(t),f(t-1),\sum_{\tau = 0}^t f(\tau))$?

Comment: Sure--but the restriction has to be far more specific than what you supply at the end of the post.  Again, the problem is that your "$F$" as a function of $t$ variables (so far) has no relationship at all with your "$F$" as a function of $t-1$ variables.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: No, all there is to say about $a_i(t)$ is that $0 \leq a_i(t) \leq 1$ for all $t$.

Comment: @whuber: Now it has three variables, not $t-1$.

Comment: Is it always the same $F$ at every step or not?  (Ordinarily one would assume so, but since your original definition allowed for it to change at each step, I have to ask.)

Comment: @whuber: Now, with three arguments, it's always the same - depending on $n$ parameters, which may vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the $n\times T$ matrix containing $a_i(t)$ $\forall \ i\in [n],t\in[0,T-1]$ and $\mathbf{a}_t=[a_1(t) \ \cdots \ a_n(t)]$. You can simplify your objective value as $c(T)=\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}C(\mathbf{a}_t)$. The resulting optimization problem is then

$\min_{A\in [0,1]^{n\times T}} c(T):=\sum_{t=0}^{T-1}C(\mathbf{a}_t)$ subject to $f(t)\leq \theta(t)\  \forall t\leq T$.

If both $C$ and $F$ are linear functions (you can express objective and $f(t)\leq \theta(t)$ constraints with a matrix product), this yields a Linear Program and you can use e.g. the Simplex or Ellipsoid methods.

If this is not the case, you can apply a primal-dual method such as [Augmented Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Lagrangian_method). [See this for some examples](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-F15/scribes/11-dual-gen-scribed.pdf). Note that the gradient of $c$ is trivial to compute given the simplified expression, and you can differentiate $f$ using the same methods as in backpropagation through time.

Comment: Did you receive the bounty? (I accepted your answer.)

Comment: Yes! Hope it solved your doubts!

Comment: There were no doubts - only missing knowledge. But you filled some gaps, thanks a lot!